# How to format the phone number with default value in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, behavior

I have used phone number formatting based on combo box selected item type. It is working fine for newly type. But when we reload/edit the existing phone number the phone number is not formatted and it is not visible. I have implemented the phone number formatting based on the below mentioned link, Please anyone give valuable suggestion to done this.

[Please refer link](https://xamarinhelp.com/masked-entry-in-xamarin-forms/)

**MyView.xaml**

```
<Entry x:Name="phoneEntry" Placeholder="Phone Number" FontSize="14" PlaceholderColor="Gray" Text="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Telephone">                                                        
  <Entry.Behaviors>                                                            
       <buttonBehavior:EntryBehavior CommandParameter="{x:Reference phoneFormat}" />
  </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

**EntryBehavior.cs**

```
public class EntryBehavior : Behavior<Entry>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public object CommandParameter
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
        }
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CommandParameter.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(EntryBehavior));

        private string format = "";
        public string Format
        {
            get => format;
            set { format = value; OnPropertyChanged(); SetPositions(); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
        {
            entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
            base.OnAttachedTo(entry);          
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
        {
            entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
        }

        IDictionary<int, char> _positions;

        void SetPositions()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Format))
            {
                _positions = null;
                return;
            }

            var list = new Dictionary<int, char>();
            for (var i = 0; i < Format.Length; i++)
                if (Format[i] != 'X')
                    list.Add(i, Format[i]);

            _positions = list;
        }

        private void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (CommandParameter != null && CommandParameter is SfComboBox)
            {
                int index = (CommandParameter as SfComboBox).SelectedIndex;
                if (index == 0)
                    Format = "(XXX) XXX-XXXX";
                else if (index == 1)
                    Format = "X(XXX) XXX-XXXX";
                else
                    Format = "";
            }

            var entry = sender as Entry;

            var text = entry.Text;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) || _positions == null)
                return;

            if (text.Length > format.Length)
            {
                entry.Text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1);
                return;
            }

            foreach (var position in _positions)
                if (text.Length >= position.Key + 1)
                {
                    var value = position.Value.ToString();
                    if (text.Substring(position.Key, 1) != value)
                        text = text.Insert(position.Key, value);
                }

            if (entry.Text != text)
                entry.Text = text;
        }
}
```

**MyViewViewModel.cs**

```
public MyViewViewModel
{
   PhoneFormat = "Type 1";
   Number = "(134) 234-3453";
}
```

Based on PhoneFormatType the phone number is formatted in the entry behavior. If Type 1 means (XXX) XXX-XXXX and if Type 2 means X(XXX) XXX-XXXX.

Comment: Please post [mcve] and not just a link to an external resource.

Comment: @Vulpex, Ok I will add my code what I have tried.